# Why doesn't $('body').html("") clear the javascript that calls it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

This is a piece of code that links to a javascript file that generates some fake tweets, along with some self made comments that attempt to explain to myself what is happening. I was wondering what the purpose of `$body.html('');` was. It seems like it just clears the contents of the body, which is already empty except for the javascript that is present. Wouldn't this also clear the actual script that inside the body as well? i.e., why doesn't the whole script just vanish when we reach that line. I'm guessing that the function is executed in its entirety before the body is cleared? Just looking for a little illumination, I guess, on function execution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="data_generator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>


  $(document).ready(function(){   // calls function only after dom is loaded                        
    var $body = $('body');        // selects html body tag, stores in $body
    $body.html('');               // clears body?

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;   // sets index to length of streams array
    while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];     // gets a tweet string
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');       // $tweet is a div element
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);  // add formatted tweet to div
      $tweet.appendTo($body);             // add tweet to body
      index -= 1;                         // rinse, repeat
    }

  });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: To be clear, I didn't write the code, only the comments. I am just trying to break it down and understand each line.

Comment: because its already loaded into memory.

Comment: The script element in the HTML should vanish, however the script is loaded into memory, modifying the HTML after that doesn't remove it from memory.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans. Is the purpose of including that line simply to clear the script? Is that a common practice?

Comment: I think its to just make sure the body is unpolluted with excess elements before putting in the tweets, but that is only a guess. Though they wouldnt have needed to clear the body if they had just included that as an external js file and put the script tag in the head.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I thought it might be something like that. I think they just have it in the html file for the sake of simplicity, but yeah I see what you're saying.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4HQ6/

Comment: Excellent @JakeBraun thanks. That's a very nice help in understanding exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, the script element does vanish, I just wasn't sure exactly how the whole thing played out. It's a very basic question that I get now, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Javascript is run the function context is stored in memory, and closed-over variables are stored in the context. They don't go away. Globals are attached to `window`.  They don't go away either.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it is a better idea to append the script to the header (where all the other scripts reside) than to the body.**

If you want to completely eliminate the script that is being called, you could use:

```
<script>
(function foo(){
    var b=function moo(){
        var c=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        alert(document.body.innerHTML);
        c[0].parentElement.removeChild(c[0]);
        alert(document.body.innerHTML);
    }
    var a=setTimeout(b,1000);
    b=null;
})();
foo=null;
</script>
```

Keep in mind, that will COMPLETELY remove any functionality of the `script` and any reference to it in the `DOM`.

Basically, because the script has already loaded, you can't just `remove` it from the `DOM`.

**Is there really any reason to get rid of it, now that it's already loaded...???**

Comment: Thank you. I am not trying to eliminate the script, I was just wondering why it wasn't eliminated via the code. I just didn't understand the purpose of the line in question, $body.html('');

Comment: Yeah, it's a memory issue. Your browser has already downloaded the script, so it will still be callable despite what you try to empty from the `HTML`.